# Issue with application/json reponse being escaped in Spring Integration 4.2

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

Creating an HTTP proxy in Spring Integration 4.2.1.RELEASE. Environment is using the latest 2.0.0.RELEASE platform BOM, including a spring-webmvc layer - running on Tomcat7.

Calls are "application/json", passed through the web layer to a different REST server endpoint (the setupUrl method rewrites the URL).  The code successfully calls the external server, gets good response, then mangles the response before it returns to the caller.

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpProxyFlow()  {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from((MessagingGateways g) ->
                    g.httpGateway("/my-service/**")
                            .messageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter())
                        .payloadFunction(httpEntity ->
                                ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                                        .getRequest()
                                        .getQueryString())
                        .requestPayloadType(String.class))
                        .handleWithAdapter(a ->
                                a.httpGateway(this::setupUrl)
                                        .httpMethodFunction(this::getMethodFunction)
                                        .errorHandler(new PassThroughErrorHandler())
                                        .encodeUri(false)
                                        .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                        ).get();
    }
```

The call directly to the REST endpoint returns

> {"affiliate":"test","producer":"TST","products"...

While the call through Spring Integration returns

> "{\"affiliate\":\"test\",\"producer\":\"TST\",\"products\":[{\"

Tried a lot of combinations of adding StringHttpMessageConverter to the outbound adapter.  Messing with the encodings (UTF-8 rather than ISO-8859-1).  Something is messing with the response string, and it seems to be AFTER it leaves Spring Integration as near as I can tell.  The last time Integration touches it is HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway.handleRequest() line 117.  It still looks correct in the response object there.

It's possible the issue is really with spring-mvc, that is the first place I see the mangled string in debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best guess is some problem with the `accept` (inbound) or `content-type` (outbound).

I just changed the http sample like so...

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="proxyChannel"
                            reply-channel="reply"
                            path="/receiveGateway"
                            supported-methods="POST"/>

<int:channel id="reply" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="proxyChannel"
                reply-channel="reply"
                expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
                url="http://localhost:8080/http/receiveGateway2"/>

<int-http:inbound-gateway request-channel="receiveChannel"
                            path="/receiveGateway2"
                            supported-methods="POST"/>

<int:channel id="receiveChannel"/>

<int:chain input-channel="receiveChannel">
    <int:header-filter header-names="content-type" />
    <int:service-activator expression='{"foo" : "bar"}'/>
</int:chain>
```

The payload being returned to the first gateway is type `String`; it works for me with an inbound `accept` of `text/plain` or `application/json`.

Since the `StringHttpMessageConverter` is ahead of the JSON message converter in the list, and the payload is a `String`, it is chosen because the type is `String` and that converter can handle `*/*` `accept`, so there's no double JSON encoding.

`{"foo":"bar"}` is received by my client.

If you can't figure it out with DEBUG logging and/or the debugger, you could try reconfiguring the inbound gateway with just a `StringHttpMessageConverter`.

Set a breakpoint at line 151 (current release) in `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` to see which outbound message converter is being selected.

Comment: I switched to the StringHttpMessageConverter only for inbound and outbound, and called setSupportedMediaTypes() with all the MediaType variations I wanted.  Now I'm running into the contentType issue https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3508 and working on that.  I'll ask another question if I can't figure that out...