# Spring Integration 4.2.1.RELEASE Content-type header not being mapped in

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I'm using the latest Spring Integration 4.2.1.RELEASE, using DSL config.  My requests are not having their HTTP Header Content-type mapped from the inbound request.

There is an old JIRA [INT-3508](https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3508) that was resolved.  And in the [4.0 to 4.1 migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.0-to-4.1-Migration-Guide), it seems to say this was fixed.

However my code is not having the header requested.

```
    @Bean
public IntegrationFlow httpProxyFlow()  {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from((MessagingGateways g) ->
                g.httpGateway("/csa-service/**")
                    .messageConverters(getMessageConverter())
                    .payloadFunction(httpEntity ->
                            ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
                                    .getRequest()
                                    .getQueryString())
                    .requestPayloadType(String.class))
                    .handleWithAdapter(a ->
                            a.httpGateway(this::setupUrl)
                                    .messageConverters(getMessageConverter())
                                    .httpMethodFunction(this::getMethodFunction)
                                    .errorHandler(new PassThroughErrorHandler())
                                    .encodeUri(false)
                                    .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                    ).get();
}

private HttpMessageConverter getMessageConverter() {
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
    stringConverter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList( //
            MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8,
            new MediaType("application", "*+json"),
            MediaType.TEXT_HTML,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    return stringConverter;
}
```

When I debug the DefaultHttpHeaderMapper, the issue is exactly what the JIRA above mentions, line 730:

```
        else if (MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
```

and that static variable maps back to

```
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "contentType";
```

The [migration guide from 3.0 to 4.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-3.0-to-4.0-Migration-Guide) shows the configuration for object-to-json-transformer and a header-enricher.  While the 4.0 guide shows

```
<int:chain>
 <int:object-to-json-transformer/>
 <int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://service"/></int:chain>
```

It seems like the equivalent in DSL is

```
        .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer())
```

However, adding that is introduces the Jackson-databind converter, which brings back the [wacked out JSON I just fixed with the help of Gary Russell on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33924009/issue-with-application-json-reponse-being-escaped-in-spring-integration-4-2).

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a workaround.

```
                .expectedResponseType(String.class)
                )
                .transform(new ObjectToJsonTransformer())
               .get();
```

Worked, but the toJson on line 97

```
    Object payload = ResultType.STRING.equals(this.resultType)
            ? this.jsonObjectMapper.toJson(message.getPayload())
            : this.jsonObjectMapper.toJsonNode(message.getPayload());
```

Cause the JSON in my payload to be re-encoded.  So I created a custom version of the class and removed that line, and everything I was testing now works.

The doTransform() method has the Content-type fix I needed, but the object doesn't seem necessary otherwise in our case.  Any suggestions on how I could implement this better would be appreciated.